# WordPress get all post in category function

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I have a simple function that I need to get all post via category,
I have two categories **`Uncategorised` with `id=1`** and **`bank` with `id=6`**

I have three post, `bank` category has 2 and `uncategorised` has 1 post.

I have a PHP file as:

cat_post.php

```
<?php
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => $noOfPost,
    'offset' => 1,
    'category' => $categoryName // set cat here
    ));
echo '<div class="recent-post">';
if ($myposts)
{
    foreach ($myposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>

        <a class="col-xs-3 col-md-2" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
        </a>

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-10">
            <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </a>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read Full</a>
            <br>
            <a class="" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
        <?php comments_number('0 Comments', '1 Comments', '% Comments'); ?>.
            </a>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
echo '</div>';
```

and I use this PHP file and set the parameters as:

second_page.php

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="banks">
        <?php
        $categoryName = 6; // sets category
        $noOfPost = 5; // no of post
        get_template_part('cat_post', get_post_format());  // gets function from cat_post.php
        ?>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="morebank">
        <h2>more content</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is showing two post from different categories, but it should be showing both post from *bank* category.

Any one know whats I'm doing wrong and why my code is not working as expected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using `global` variable like this:
*in `cat_post.php`*

```
<?php
global $post;
global $categoryName; //access it through a global variable.
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => $noOfPost,
    'offset' => 1,
    'category' => $categoryName // set cat here
));
```

and set `global $categoryName` value in `second_page.php` as like this:

```
...
<?php
global $categoryName;
$categoryName = 6; // sets category
$noOfPost = 5; // no of post
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm it seems to work on post that have comments but if no comment then it still wont show, but plus 1 for help

Comment: @BenjaminOats: can you do one test write `get_posts` function in your `second_page.php` file and just print the result, and check you are getting desired output or not?